# How to get thumbnail snapshot of video and pdf file in php

Tags: php, video-capture

Can anyone help me out that how i can display video and pdf file as thumbnail?? 
Thanks..............

Answer (score 5):

For the PDF you can use Imagick.

[How it's done is here in great detail](http://valokuva.org/?p=7=1)

For the video snapshot, you can use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). Here's an example code.

```
// this will create many images
$thumb = exec("ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%d.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've used this in a project and it works brilliantly.

Comment: First link is broken (goes to a placeholder nginx page).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageMagick's PHP](http://www.php.net/imagick) class. Supports both [video and PDF.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)

Comment: Imagick's video support is very very limited on what codecs it can read.